# GhostScript hangs when direct printing

Tags: c#, windows, printing, ghostscript

we are trying to directly print  PDF files from our Intranet application using GhostScript 9.18, with this architecture:

- Windows Server 2012 r2 64
- GhostScript for Windows 9.18 (tried both with 32 and 64 bits versions)

But for our purpose testing i am simply testing from the command line.
When i type in the commande line :

```
gswin32c.exe -dPrinted -dNOPAUSE -dNumCopies=1  -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%\\creeks\K42N1CN1" "D:\temp\test.pdf"
```

Where \creeks\K42N1CN1 is my NetWork Window Printer (Kyiocera).

The gswin32c.exe is hanging. I do not see any good explanation on the message box or in the event viewer. But i can post the whole message if needed.

Interesting details are :

- if i give an incorrect printer name,GhostScipt popup the standard windows printing dialog box, I choose the same network printer then the document is printed perfectly
- the conversion from PDF files to raster image (png) is working wery well.
- the problem is the same on and admin command prompt
- removing all optional parametres did change something

Maybe i suspect  :

- an incorrect value of the -sDEVICE parameter
- a memory acces viloation because when i try to debug the GhostScript program i get the message "Exception non gérée à 0x101eddc9 dans gswin32c.exe : 0xC0000005: Violation d'accès lors de la lecture de l'emplacement 0x3130654e." (sorry it is french).

Any help is appreciated here from Toulouse\France

Best regards

Event viewer crash report :

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=130953327000374373
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=a7aa1a77-a94e-11e5-80d6-0050569e7a66
IntegratorReportIdentifier=a7aa1a76-a94e-11e5-80d6-0050569e7a66
WOW64=1
NsAppName=gswin32c.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Nom de l’application
Sig[0].Value=gswin32c.exe
Sig[1].Name=Version de l’application
Sig[1].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Horodatage de l’application
Sig[2].Value=56123d4d
Sig[3].Name=Nom du module par défaut
Sig[3].Value=gsdll32.dll
Sig[4].Name=Version du module par défaut
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Horodateur du module par défaut
Sig[5].Value=56123d49
Sig[6].Name=Code de l’exception
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Décalage de l’exception
Sig[7].Value=001eddc9
DynamicSig[1].Name=Version du système
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Identificateur de paramètres régionaux
DynamicSig[2].Value=1036
DynamicSig[22].Name=Information supplémentaire n° 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=3376
DynamicSig[23].Name=Information supplémentaire n° 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=3376824fd83b1dc3948a498a9c840064
DynamicSig[24].Name=Information supplémentaire n° 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=7929
DynamicSig[25].Name=Information supplémentaire n° 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=792969fd05f031b74b3a51636e7a67ec
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe
UI[3]=gswin32c.exe a cessé de fonctionner
UI[4]=Windows peut rechercher une solution au problème en ligne.
UI[5]=Rechercher une solution en ligne et fermer le programme
UI[6]=Rechercher ultérieurement une solution en ligne et fermer le programme
UI[7]=Fermer le programme
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SYSFER.DLL
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.18\bin\gsdll32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\comdlg32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.DLL
FriendlyEventName=Fonctionnement arrêté
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=gswin32c.exe
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=C5D66B61522557FE3034ACFE0B05988E
```

Comment: Added the Windows Event Viewer as attchament if it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash reports are rarely (if ever) useful. Its hard to see how you would be getting an access violation when debugging, and not getting such a message when not debugging the executable.

However there was a recent fix in this area:

http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=4703d04a6146904cab9b1b04aee1478e31df52da

So you might like to get the *current* bleeding edge source, rebuild and try it. If you want to debug Ghostscript you will need to get the source and build a debug executable anyway, trying to debug the release binary is an exercise in futility.....

Oh, and setting DEVICE= to something other than mswinpr2 will simply mean that it won't print to your printer, the mswinpr2 device is the only Ghostscript device which prints to Windows printers.

Comment: Waouuu... compiling the GS librairie was not  scheduled in my projet !!! But at least the fix was done, but do i have to compile by myself using the documentation [link]http://ghostscript.com/doc/8.54/Make.htm#PC_build . I dont have the necessary software right now to to it. Is there any nightly build proposed for downloading or do i have to wait next release ?

Comment: There are no builds available beyond the 6 monthly releases. I'm not saying this fix will help you, just that it is related and might. If you want a binary with this fix before March you will have to build it yourself. The Community (free) edition of VS 2013 is known to work for building Ghostscript from source, its pretty easy.

Comment: i confirm this is the problem. Don't i have time to recompile.. i will use the convert function which is working very well. Best regards

Comment: I also had this issue and if you go to http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ you can see past releases. Using the gs916w32.exe allowed me to print on windows without it crashing.